# mvc4 application environments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How to check the environment dynamically in mvc4 application, I want to set variables for local development on the local server (`http://localhost`) and disable the variables in the production.

Also, how to set the URL.Action to forward to `http://URLs` in the development environment, and in the publishing environment to forward to `https://URLs`

I'm new to mvc4 development.

Thanx,

Comment: In what kind of links? hard-coded or @Html.ActionLink() ?

Comment: I'm using @URL.Action()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010+ provides the ability to transform the webconfig file depending if it is the Debug or Release build (or something else). So you could just use 2 webconfig files, one for the development and one for the production.